# Rethinkdb, Python, and Filter

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

So here's a fun reduced snippet on some code I'm working on in Python 2.7 with the latest RethinkDB (1.14). My problem is now I need to add another condition, and there's too many possible combinations. Can this be done in a single filter statement?

```
query = r.table('messages').order_by(r.desc('created'))
if tag is not None and read is not None:
    query = query.filter(lambda n: (n['user_id'] == user_id) &
                           (n['tags'].contains(tag)) &
                           (n['read'] == read))
elif read is not None:
    query = query.filter(lambda n: (n['user_id'] == user_id) &
                           (n['read'] == read))
elif tag is not None:
    query = query.filter(lambda n: (n['user_id'] == user_id) &
                           (n['tags'].contains(tag)))
else:
    query = query.filter(lambda n: n['user_id'] == user_id)
fields_list = query.skip(skip)\
                   .limit(limit)\
                   .run(g.db_conn)
```

As a side note, this would be *so* much easier if chained filters worked, essentially acting as an `and`. But it seems for now you can only have one filter per RethinkDB query.

Edit: Not sure what was happening before, but chaining filters does work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this actually works!

```
def _(n):
    return (n['user_id'] == user_id) & \
           (n['tags'].contains(tag) if tag is not None else True) & \
           (n['read'] == read if read is not None else True)
query = r.table('messages') \
         .order_by(r.desc('created')) \
         .filter(_) \
         .skip(skip)\
         .limit(limit)
fields_list = query.run(g.db_conn)
```

Edit: Also possible:

```
query = r.table('messages') \
         .order_by(r.desc('created')) \
         .filter(r.row['user_id'] == user_id) \
         .filter(r.row['tags'].contains(tag) if tag is not None else True) \
         .filter(r.row['read'] == read if read is not None else True) \
         .skip(skip) \
         .limit(limit)
fields_list = query.run(g.db_conn)
```

Comment: Chaining filters should work fine and make this easier what happens when you try it?

Comment: You're right, I must have been running into a different issue that made it appear that way. I've updated the answer. Thanks!